# what is the difference between using a tab and using a button(to try to make it looks like the tabs)?

Tags: android

From the UI point of view, those 2 ways can be more less the same.

Is there any real difference?

Because using the `Buttons` way to implement `Tabs` really make thing easier, you just simply copy and paste the `Buttons` on each page to make it looks like a `Tab`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big difference is that android designed [`Tabs`](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html) with all the normal functionality of [`Tabs`](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html). Giving you a lot of the expected features of a [`Tab`](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html).

[`Buttons`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) are designed with the functionality that you would expect for a [`Button`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html).

If you are wanting to use [`Tabs`](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html) in your application, you should use [`Tabs`](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html), do not try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Could you give some solid examples? Because from my understanding the tabs and buttons are the same if they are designed for to just navigate between pages of the app.

Comment: Look at speedtest app, their tabs look very much like a button to me.
https://www.google.com/search?hl=zh-TW&q=speedtest%20app&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=643&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=JlUQUNv1FYPd0QGzjIGwCA

Comment: Can you post a more specific image? I am not sure i am seeing the tabs in the pictures you linked.

Comment: I will post again:
http://iappsin.com/speedtest-net-mobile-speed-test-app-for-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad.htm

Answer (score 1):

Tab is available in all screens and uses tab host.best example is music player app in any android device..
Button are mores specific for user event control.you can configure any user click event on button 
they both can be used in different situation.
Tab can be used same as web tab which is available in all screens(or pages in web site)
and button may be used in situation like send button or cancel button etc..